# Creating a make file

Tags: c, makefile

I know there is infinite amount of resources on the Internet with regards makefiles, but it is something that I still do not understand it. At the moment I have 3 c files PolyCalculatorMain.c PolyCalculator.c PolyCalculator.h and Polyfunctions.c

So far I have

```
PolyCalculator: PolyCalculator.o PolyCalculatorMain.c
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -o PolyCalculator PolyCalculatorMain.c PolyCalculator.o

PolyCalculator.o:   PolyCalculator.c 
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -c PolyCalculator.c PolyCalculator.h

clean:
     rm PolyCalculator *.o *~ *#
```

Any help or explanation on were to go to complete this file would be much appreciated.
Note Im only beginning so I dont want any complex code as I will not understand it

Comment: Note I do not know why the code, is not in the same format I posted in.

Comment: Which c files use polynomial.h?

Comment: All of the C files use the header as that is where I put my function declarations and library's

Comment: The filenames in the makefile don't match the filenames in your description.

Comment: Sorry I will fix that now

Comment: Does this not work? It looks OK except for the .h in the compiler command. That is not normally done.

Comment: It does but im not sure how to add another C file Polyfunctions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compile command you don't normally specify .h files. They are included by the preprocessor (which runs before the compiler) as it encounters #include statements. That is the only thing I can see.

The .h files do show up in Makefiles as dependencies since changes to them can require code that uses them to need to be recompiled.

I would say the basic rule is to include anything on the dependency line which would cause a recompile to be necessary if they changed.

```
PolyCalculator: PolyCalculator.o PolyFunctions.o PolyCalculatorMain.c
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -o PolyCalculator PolyCalculatorMain.c PolyCalculator.o PolyFunctions.o

PolyCalculator.o:   PolyCalculator.c PolyCalculator.h
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -c PolyCalculator.c 

PolyFunctions.o: PolyFunctions.c PolyFunctions.h
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -c PolyFunctions.c

clean:
 rm PolyCalculator *.o *~ *#
```

Makefiles allow you to have variables that can be reused. For example, you can have your
compiler options in a variable:

```
options=-Wall -ggdb
```

and then you use them with brackets and a dollar sign

```
gcc ${options}
```

You can also break them up:

```
debug=-ggdb

warnings=-Wall

options=${warnings} ${debug}
```

You can also combine all your object files into a variable:

```
obj_files=PolyCalculator.o PolyFunctions.o 

PolyCalculator: ${obj_files} PolyCalculatorMain.c
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -o PolyCalculator PolyCalculatorMain.c ${obj_files}

PolyCalculator.o:   PolyCalculator.c PolyCalculator.h
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -c PolyCalculator.c 

PolyFunctions.o: PolyFunctions.c PolyFunctions.h
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -c PolyFunctions.c

clean:
     rm PolyCalculator *.o *~ *#
```

Comment: Hi Scooter thank you for the information about header files, but do you know how I could add another C file to my makefile

Comment: @Eamonn I edited the answer to handle another C file.

Comment: Can you recommend any good resource on makefiles? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Eamonn OReilly published a book on Make which they have now made free: http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/make3/book/index.csp

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't give really clear detains of what you would want changed / modified, I giving you what I would write the makefile as below, although some might (will?) disagree with me in places.
I see that you edited you original post and mention a PolyFunctions.cpp (and I guesssing that there
is a PolyFunctions.h)

```
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-ansi -Wall -pedantic
INCS=

LK=gcc
LKFLAGS=
LIBS=

OBJS = PolyCalculator.o PolyCalculatorMain.o PolyFunctions.o

PROG = PolyCalculator


$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
        $(LK) $(LKFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $(PROG)

rebuild : clean $(PROG)

PolyCalculatorMain.o : PolyCalculatorMain.cpp PolyCalculator.h PolyFunctions.h
        $(GCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCS) PolyCalculatorMain.cpp -o PolyCalculatorMain.o

PolyCalculator.o : PolyCalculator.cpp PolyCalculator.h
        $(GCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCS) PolyCalculator.cpp -o PolyCalculator.o   

PolyFunctions.o : PolyFunctions.c PolyFunctions.h
        $(GCC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INCS) PolyFunctions.cpp -o PolyFunctions.o  

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(PROG) *.o *~ *#
```

OK, the changes that I made (and why)

1. First I like using variables that are then expanded as rules are fired.  I find this a convenient way to insure that all steps use the same settings.  Also, I have added variables that you can use if you need to add headers to compilation (i.e. the `INCS` variable).  I have broken out the commands and flags for the linker as well, the `LK`, `LKFLAGS` and `LIBS` variable.  Currently most of these are empty.
2. I added a variable for the various object files that are created, I like doing this because if I add a new source file to the project I have to do two things, the first would be to write a rule for it and the second would be to add it to the `OBJS` variable.  In my opinion, the more things I need to do when adding a new source file, the greater the chance that I will forget something.
3. I added a variable for the final program name.  Again, makes it simple if I want to change it…and I'm lazy — typing `$(PROG)` is easier and less error prone than typing `PolyCalculator` :)
4. Ordering of targets is a personal choice, I always put the target to rebuild the main program as the first (or default) target in the makefile.  That way when I run `make` I just build what has changed since my last build.  I put a rule near the top to do a total rebuild of the application, in the above this is the `rebuild` rule.  Running `make rebuild` is operationally equivalent to `make clean; make`; but I prefer a single target to accomplish this
5. I rewrote your rules using the variable I defined in point 1.
6. I added the `-f` flag to `rm` so clean will do everything even if it can't find a file.  Again, this tends to be personal preference.

Comment: I'm not clear why you changed his source code to C++ when he is asking about C, but otherwise this is good.

Comment: I plead turkey-addled mind :).  It was unintentionally, I normally program in C++ and I guess my fingers just added that extra `pp` to the end of every extension.  At least I didn't change the compiler from `gcc` to `g++`.....

Answer (score 1):

I make sure to use macros extensively, because you can redefine macros on the `make` command line if need be.  There are also many standard macros, such as `CC` for the name of the C compiler and CFLAGS for the (majority) of the flags passed to the compiler.  Also, `make` has built-in rules for many operations, such as converting a `.c` file into a `.o` file.

The philosophy behind `make` is that compilation is expensive, so you do as little of it as possible, but as much as necessary.  Thus, `make` is typically commanded to build object files, and then links the object files with libraries to build programs.

You say you have three source files and one header.  So, my makefile for your program would include:

```
FILES.c = PolyCalculatorMain.c PolyCalculator.c Polyfunctions.c
FILES.o = ${FILES.c:.c=.o}
PROGRAM = PolyCalculator

CFLAGS  = -Wall -ggdb

all: ${PROGRAM}

${PROGRAM}: ${FILES.o}
    ${CC} -o $@ ${CFLAGS} ${FILES.o} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDLIBS}

PolyCalculatorMain.o: PolyCalculator.h
PolyCalculator.o:     PolyCalculator.h
Polyfunctions.o:      PolyCalculator.h

clean:
     rm -f ${PROGRAM} *.o *~ *# core a.out
```

The choice between `$(XYZ)` and `${XYZ}` is arbitrary; I chose to use curly brackets 30 years ago, and don't see a reason to change.  Being consistent is what matters.

The `FILES.c` macro (yes, macro names may contain dots, despite the fact that `vim` doesn't colour them as macros) lists a set of three file names.  If I needed to add a fourth, then I'd add it to this list. If the list got too long for a single line, I'd use a macro of the format:

```
FILES.c = \
    PolyCalculatorMain.c \
    PolyCalculator.c \
    Polyfunctions.c
```

This allows editing of one line affected when a file is added unless you add it at the end of the list.  I normally keep such lists in sorted order.

The `FILES.o` macro is defined by applying a suffix-transformation rule to the `FILES.c` macro.  The part after the `:` is `.c=.o`; it means replace the names that end with `.c` with `.o` at the end.

The PROGRAM macro is what I use in a single-program makefile.  For a multi-program makefile, each program gets its own macro in all caps.  (Although `make` macros are not constrained to all caps, it is normal to use all caps for macros.)  The CFLAGS macros sets your chosen options for the C compiler.  Good marks for using `-Wall`.  I use more stringent options like `-Wextra -Werror` and specify a standard (`-std=c11`), but `-Wall` is a good start.

It is conventional to have the first rule in your makefile called `all`.  It says "everything is up to date when `${PROGRAM}` is up to date".

The next rule says that the program depends on the object files.  If any of the object files is newer than the program, you rebuild the program using the command line shown.  The `$@` hieroglyph is the same as `${PROGRAM}` in this rule.  Formally, it is the name of the target being built.  It makes the command line generic — everything except the `-o` is a macro.  This tends to be the way that `makefiles` work; the information is almost all in macros.  The `${LDFLAGS}` and `${LDLIBS}` macros are semi-standard; they allow you to pass options to the linker (`ld`, invoked by the C compiler), and are used to specify library-related options.  For example, you might have:

```
LDFLAGS = -L ${OTHERLIBDIR}
LDLIBS  = -l${OTHERLIB}
```

to link with a library not located in `/usr/lib` and other standard locations.  The macros `OTHERLIBDIR` and `OTHERLIB` would be defined earlier in the `makefile`, of course.

The next three lines say that the object files (note that it is the object files, not the source files) depend on the header file.  `make` is quite capable of deducing that `PolyCalculatorMain.o` is built from `PolyCalculatorMain.c`, so you don't have to specify that dependency explicitly.  It can't deduce the header dependency so you have to specify it.  Note that I've not specified a custom command, so the default command will be used.  That's usually:

```
${CC} -c ${CFLAGS} $*.c
```

where the `$*` is a shorthand for the basename of the file being compiled.

I modified the `clean` command to use `rm -f` (which won't complain if the arguments are missing), and added `a.out` and `core` to the list of debris files.

You can add endless extra stuff to a basic `makefile` like this.  You might add a `depend` rule to automatically generate the header dependencies; that is useful when your code begins to get complex with multiple headers, and different source files using different sets of headers.  If you have a multi-lingual source tree, you have to worry about multiple lists of files.  If you have multiple programs, you have to separate the files specific to one program from those common to several, and then think about whether to build the common object files into a local convenience library so that you don't have to list the exact dependencies for each program.

But this outline will get you going.

If you're using GNU `make`, you might well add a line:

```
.PHONY: all clean
```

This tells GNU `make` that there won't be files called `all` and `clean` created.

I note in passing that the name `Polyfunctions.c` is inconsistent with the other two; the `F` should be capitalized for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper GNU `make` file for your project:

```
# set macro with list of source files in current directory using wildcard
# note: the ':=' states that the list is to only be generated once
#       if only '='  were used, the the list would be re-generated each time referenced
SRCS := $(wildcard: *.c)

# set macro with list of object files using pattern substitution
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# set macro with list of header files in the current directory using wildcard
HDRS := $(wildcard: *.h)

# set macro with list of compiler flags
# there are many other very useful compiler flags
# but this list will result in:
#    all warnings displayed
#    compile only
#    debug info being include 
#        (there are other forms of the -g parameter to get more debug info)
#    no optimization
#    look for some included files in the current directory
CFLAGS := -Wall -c -g -O0 -I.

# set macro with list of linker flags 
#    all warnings displayed
#    debug info being included
LFLAGS := -Wall -g

# set macro with path+name of pre-processor/compiler/linker utility
# by convention, the utility is referenced by $(CC)
CC := /usr/bin/gcc

# by 'make' design, the make utility is referenced by $(MAKE)

# set macro with path+name of file deletion utility
# by convention, the utility is referenced by $(RM)
RM := /usr/bin/rm -f

# by convention, there are (at least) two phony target names
# tell 'make' that 'all' and 'clean' are targets that will NOT produce an output file 
# with those names
.PHONY: all clean

# this is first target so will be performed if:
#     user enters 'make' with no parameters
# or  user enters 'make all'
# the PolyCalculator executable is stated to be a pre-requisite 
all: PolyCalculator 


# this is a real target
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of the files listed in the OBJS macro
# the executable name is defined by the '-o' and following name
# use the parameters listed in the LFLAGS macro
PolyCalculator: $(OBJS)
    gcc $(LFLAGS) -o PolyCalculator $(OBJS)

# this is a real target (PolyCalculator.o)
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of file: PolyCalculator.c 
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of the files listed in the HDRS macro
# use the parameters listed in the CFLAGS macro
# target 'PolyCalculator' lists PolyCalculator.o as a pre-requisite
#    so it can be performed automatically
# it can also be performed directly when the user enters 'make PolyCalculator.o'
PolyCalculator.o:   PolyCalculator.c $(HDRS)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o PolyCalculator.o PolyCalculator.c

# this is a real target (PolyCalculatorMain.o)
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of file: PolyCalculatorMain.c 
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of the files listed in the HDRS macro
# use the parameters listed in the CFLAGS macro
# target 'PolyCalculator' lists PolyCalculatorMain.o as a pre-requisite
#    so it can be performed automatically
# it can also be performed directly when the user enters 'make PolyCalculatorMain.o'
PolyCalculatorMain.o:   PolyCalculatorMain.c $(HDRS)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o PolyCalculatorMain.o PolyCalculatorMain.c 


# this is a real target (PolyFunctions.o)
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of file: PolyFunctions.c 
# state that this target has a pre-requisite of the files listed in the HDRS macro
# use the parameters listed in the CFLAGS macro
# target 'PolyCalculator' lists PolyFunctions.o as a pre-requisite
#    so it can be performed automatically
# it can also be performed directly when the user enters 'make PolyFunctions.o'
PolyFunctions.o:   PolyFunctions.c $(HDRS)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o PolyFunctions.o PolyFunctions.c 

# this is a phony target (see .PHONY, above)
# it is performed when the user enters 'make clean'
clean:
    $(RM) PolyCalculator *.o *~ *#
```

Comment: One minor nitpick: you define `CC := /usr/bin/gcc` but don't then use `${CC}` anywhere.  Your notations show you are using GNU `make`; things like `$(wildcard *.c)` won't work in other versions of `make`, in general (unless they emulate GNU `make`).  Personally, I don't like wildcard rules; it means you can't have other source files (experiments, etc) kicking around in a directory; you can only have exactly the files that need to be compiled to produce the program.  I prefer an explicit list of the specific files to be built into a program — YMMV, though.

Comment: Also note that `-Wall` doesn't really mean 'all warnings'; adding `-Wextra` adds extra warnings, and there are other (generally more esoteric and usually less helpful) warnings that are not enabled even with both those.  Also, some warnings do not appear at `-O0` warning level; you need higher levels of optimization to get them to appear.  These are generally warnings related to flow control, such as detecting whether a variable is set before it is used, or is set but not used, etc.